# using limit and offset only for specific where

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where pos in ('slider', 'right', 'below') limit " . $limit . " offset " . $offset);
```

This gives me posts where `pos` is `slider` or `right` or `below` with limit and offset params.

What I need is:
- select all posts with `pos` = `slider` or `right` - without `limit` and `offset`
- plus - posts with `pos` = `below` - using `limit` and `offset` params.

It can be done using twice `$stmt` but I need to join the two selections for processing all selected posts at once.

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where pos in ('slider', 'right')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM posts where pos = 'below' limit 8");
```

Syntax error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union would work for you since both queries would return the same data set, you could then process all results at once.

```
$sql = "
    (select all posts with pos = slider or right - without limit and offset)
    UNION
    (select all posts with pos = below - using limit and offset params)
;";
```

Comment: I tried, but for some reason - doesn't work. Please see my update.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Post the complete query so I can see.

Comment: I did. Thanks for your patiance :)

Comment: You are missing 3 parentheses. One before and after the first select and one after the second select.

Comment: $stmt = $db->query("(SELECT * FROM posts where pos in ('slider', 'right'))
UNION
(SELECT * FROM posts where pos = 'below' limit 8)");